# Type error adding list<T> to listbox in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox, visual-studio-2019

intialising the list of class Staff

```
List<Staff> sList = new List<Staff>();
```

Here is the function with the error. This function will be splashed into button functions and such to display the updated data, for example after an edit or a new staff being made it will automatically update the listbox.

```
public void Reload()
    {
        lboxStaff.Items.Clear();
        lboxStaff.Items.AddRange(sList.ToArray());
    }
```

The error is specifically highlighting the "sList.ToArray()" part. The error reads as "Arguement 1: cannot convert from 'Assignment_1.Staff[]' to 'System.Windows.Form.ListViewItem[]'

I have done this type of thing before and vaguely remember having to use the .ToArray() function but that doesnt seem to be working. I have also tried using .ToList() and just using sList without any functions but neither of those work either.

Not sure if this is relevant but the class is public partial.

Comment: A ListViewItem it a Type that is used by a ListView Control, not a ListBox. You cannot use `AddRange()` to add an array of custom objects, you need to build a `ListViewItem[]` array. Or use a ListBox and set your `List<Staff>` as the DataSource; also specify a DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.

Comment: Thank you, Jimi. Your comment let me realise that I accidentally used a ListView instead of a Listbox.

Comment: If you want to update your ListBox, you may prefer a `BindingList<Staff>`, or use a BindingSource and set your `List<Staff>` as its DataSource, then set the BindingSource as the DataSource of the ListBox. Then make your `Staff` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. After that, if you add a new `Staff` object to the list or you change a property value of a `Staff` instance, the LIstBox will reflect the change immediately. No need for stuff like `lboxStaff.Items.Clear();`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can use [ListControl.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListControl_DataSource) property to add list to listbox.

Here is a code example you can refer to.

```
public void Reload()
        {
            List<Staff> sList = new List<Staff>();

            sList.Add(new Staff() { Name = "A", Age = 11 });
            sList.Add(new Staff() { Name = "B", Age = 12 });
            listBox1.DataSource = slist;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "Age";
        }
    }
    public class Staff 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }
```

Or add items in ListBox.

```
 public void Reload()
        {
            List<Staff> sList = new List<Staff>();

            sList.Add(new Staff() { Name = "A", Age = 11 });
            sList.Add(new Staff() { Name = "B", Age = 12 });
             for (int i = 0; i < sList.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(sList.ElementAt(i));
            
            }
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "Age";
        }
```

Comment: Curious why you didn't use a foreach in the second example..?